# rdtsc under WSL2 lacks nonstop_tsc?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hyper-v, rdtsc

I'm doing some microbenchmarking of short code snippets using the `__rdtsc` intrinsic inside WSL2 on Windows 11. I'm noticing that there is a lot more variance in the results than I'm used to from working on machines that are running Linux on bare metal. If I use `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` instead my results across runs are much more consistent. From prior experience this made me suspect that the TSC might not be reliable, so I ran `dmesg` and found this:

```
tsc: Marking TSC unstable due to running on Hyper-V
```

Which is surprising because that directly contradicts the documentation [here](https://kernel.org/doc/html//v6.1-rc3/virt/hyperv/clocks.html):

> Hyper-V initialization code in Linux reads this MSR to get the frequency, so it skips TSC calibration **and sets tsc_reliable**.

Any ideas why this is happening? Is there a way for me to use plain `__rdtsc`? I notice my `/proc/cpuinfo` does have `constant_tsc` but not `nonstop_tsc`, but since my CPU is new enough to be running Windows 11 I assume this is an artifact of running in WSL2.

Comment: `clock_gettime` uses scale factors for RDTSC to compute an offset since the last timer tick (the thing you could read with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE`).  That requires `constant_tsc` but not `nonstop_tsc`, at least on real hardware where the kernel can be sure when the underlying CPU was asleep.  (I guess it uses a different mechanism to update the coarse clock on wakeups.)  IDK about the situation on Windows / Hyper-V.  You might single-step into the VDSO stub in a call to `clock_gettime` in a running process and see if it uses RDTSC at all.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you edited the title wrong? I state in the last paragraph that `/proc/cpuinfo` does have `constant_tsc`.

Comment: Oops, yeah, I got it backwards.